# Installing Tensorflow on ARM64

Tags: tensorflow, virtual-machine, apple-m1, ubuntu-20.04

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 ARM64 through UTM on an Apple Silicon Mac. Is there a way to install Tensorflow (preferably 1.15) without building from source? The process seems overly complicated.

Comment: There's no GUI installation, only source or package. It might seem overwhelming, just follow the instructions and you'll be fine

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any aarch64 package available, only x86-x64

Comment: Hi! Have you checked instruction in these two links yet?  
  https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin#usage 
   https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm

Comment: @TensorflowSupport The first link worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use Anaconda/miniconda + conda-forge. See [M1 Mac Tensorflow VS Code Rosetta2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73461385/m1-mac-tensorflow-vs-code-rosetta2)

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```