# M1 Mac Tensorflow VS Code Rosetta2

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1, rosetta

I'm struggling to install tensorflow with a M1 mac. I've got python 3.9.7 and Monterrey 12.3 and apple silicon visual studio code. There is an apple solution involving miniconda apple dependancies and tensorflow-macos and tensorflow-metal. However this solution is not good for me as I have to use Rosetta2 emulator for multiple packages including PyQt5 etc. I was wondering if anyone has been able to use their M1 macs and pip installed tensorflow in a venv rosetta terminal. Thank you.

Kevin

Comment: I would also like to achieve the same since some of the dependencies in my package are not available for ARM and I managed to install them with Rosetta. Did you have any luck? I know I was able to install tensorflow 2.4 with Big Sur but since I upgraded to Monterey it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Running TensorFlow on miniforge + conda-forge (arm64)

TensorFlow can run natively on M1 (arm64) macs. A highly recommended, easy way to install TensorFlow on arm64 macs is to [via conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow). You should install python via [miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#download) or [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), because there is an arm64 (Apple Sillicon) distribution. With this, as of today, you can install the latest version 2.10.0 of TensorFlow:

```bash
$ lipo -archs $(which python3)   # python3 is running natively as arm64
arm64
$ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Note: `tensorflow-macos` 2.4.0 is obsolete so you shouldn't be using that.

### But still want Rosetta 2? Try conda-forge.

If you really need to have python running on Rosetta 2 (x86_64) in cases where **some packages does not support arm64**,
you can still install TensorFlow with a macOS x86_64 release via conda. Installing via `pip` and PyPI repository won't work here, because you will run into `Illegal hardware instruction` segfault because Google's official TF macos-x86_64 wheel releases on PyPI assumes a target platform that has AVX instructions.

```bash
$ lipo -archs $(which python3)   # x86_64 means Rosetta 2
x86_64
$ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow       # install via conda
$ python -c 'import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)'
```

Comment: Jeez, I'm stupid, didn't know it was that easy. I spent one day trying to compile tensorflow on macos using Bazel x86 on the M1 mac. Thanks!